# Issue when trying to work with a net 48 application after using .net core 3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I get a System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException with a lot of loader exeptions "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0," when trying to run my web application. It work before I installed .net core 3.

I tried to uninstall .net core 3. But that didn't help.
I don't have any bindingRedirects.

Anyone with the same problem? Anyone with a solution?